# C# HtmlAgilityPack Parser Как отключить смену курсора мыши при фоновой загрузке страницы

Tags: c#, парсер, webbrowser, cursor, htmlagilitypack

В программе на WinForms есть браузер от HtmlAgilityPack, он в фоне парсит страницы сайта, проблема заключается в том что при каждом обращении парсера к странице курсор мыши в программе меняется на "стрелку с крутящимся кругом" [image: введите сюда описание изображения] , получается курсор постоянно мигает с обычной стрелки на стрелку с загрузкой, это разрдажает, был еще звук щелчка но я его уже убрал программно, осталось убрать этот курсор загрузки, но не знаю как, подскажите пожалуйста. Предоставлю кусок кода парсера чтобы понять о чем идет речь

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

var web = new HtmlWeb();
web.BrowserTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
var html = web.LoadFromBrowser(url).ParsedText;

var htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

var divs = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("glbg")).ToList();
```

Comment: Асинхронность в C# изучи.

Comment: Хорошо, обязательно. Так подскажешь как убрать курсор?

Comment: @Saltant Вам намекают, что этим курсором система вам намекает, что основной UI поток занят. Если вы запустите парсер асинхронно, либо в отдельном потоке - UI поток разгрузится и курсор будет обычным.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Ок гляну как переделать функции с использованием async/await пока просто в винде сменил значок курсора чтоб не маячил...

Comment: @ГеннадийП Спасибо Геннадий, добавил ниже ответ на свой вопрос, открыл новый поток для парсера. Может кому пригодится моё решение, Вам Спасибо!

Comment: @Saltant решение на потоке так себе. Лучше асинхронная функция или асинхронная лямбда.

Comment: @SmInc К сожалению я не нашел в документации HtmlAgilityPack асинхронный парсинг с веб браузера, там есть только асинхронный метод загрузки интернет страниц, а мне нужно именно с открытого браузера т.к я логинюсь на сайте с которого веду парсинг и мне подходит только метод LoadFromBrowser(), возможно агилити пак не лучшее решение для парсинга, но это первое на которое я натолкнулся.

Comment: @Saltant HAP тут ни при чем. ты же поток создаешь не учитывая HAP, так же и с асихронностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решил проблему открытием нового потока для парсера** Курсор больше не маячит "вечной загрузкой".

```
        public static void MyMethod()
        {

            Thread ThA = new Thread(
() =>   {


    Console.WriteLine("ТУТ ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ КОД МЕТОДА MyMethod()");

    Application.Run();

        }
);
            ThA.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            ThA.IsBackground = true;
            ThA.Start();
        }
```